# Angular catching "standard" errors instead of my API's errors

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a service that looks like this:

```
return this.http
      .post(requestUrl, body, { headers, observe: 'response' })
      .toPromise()
      .then((res: any) => {
        return res.body?.data || res?.body?.message;
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('error', err);
      })
```

When i trigger an error, this is what i get on the console.log:

```
error Error Code: 400
Message: Http failure response for <MY API ENDPOINT>: 400 OK
```

But on the network tab (Google chrome dev tools) i see this:

```
{
    "message": "Unsupported value, please contact support.",
    "status": "failure"
}
```

How can i read my message that i'm sending from my Backend in my angular .catch block?

Comment: I'd recommend reading https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details, and leaning into RxJS (at least stop using `toPromise`, which is deprecated).

Comment: @jonrsharpe sadly this is not my entire code and im trying to "patch" this in the most short way as possible. I've read the guide at angular.io but they're using Observables, correct? Is there something i can do with my current code to read the backend response?

Comment: You can move the conversion to a promise _later_ to keep your current API. You can also look in more detail at what err is, what properties it has.